# What are options for database management for cloud computing (chrome os specifically)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cloud, google-chrome-os

I'm currently attempting to do my development on Chrome OS.  I've found some very useful services with Google Drive and also services such as Nitrous.io. However, the part that is causing issues is finding a suitable replacement to database management.  Currently, I've been using SQL Server on Windows.  I don't mind transitioning to sqlite, mysql, etc. but I'm looking for a cloud solution to it.  Free (perhaps sqlite stored on google drive?) would be nice, but I'm not opposed to paid hosting options.  Has anyone transitioned to Chrome OS or something similar where they are doing their database management in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [Google cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) which gives you the power of MySQL as a service. It has some powerful options and you can use it both from google app engine and google compute engine.
Of course, that you can try amazon SQL options as well at: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/ which contain a nice sets of RDSs.
If you wish noSQL solutions there are many options out there:

1. Google datastore - It's a powerful technology that bring you lots of power.
2. Amazon - http://aws.amazon.com/nosql/
3. http://tour.mongohq.com/